# Google map current location Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps

I'm trying to render a Google map with the user current location but it only renders the default location(around Europe area) no matter what I do. Since I am new to Swift, I am not sure how to debug this and want to ask here to figure out what I need to do.

**Swift code**

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }

    private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a real device'? No gps in Simulator.

Comment: Just running on Simulator would not render the current location of the user?

Comment: No. You can use one of the small icons above the console to pick a 'simulated' location, but the simulator defaults to no user location.

Comment: I tried on my device but it still renders Europe area. I already put 'NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription' in my info.plist and the alert pops up when I start the app but it does not take me to the current location. Any advice?

Comment: Try commenting out `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` the very first location could be very inaccurate i.e. Somewhere in the northern hemisphere.

Comment: The didUpdateLocations method is called continuously as the gps gradually gets more and more accurate fixes on your position. Only stop it once you have an accurate `enough` fix.

Comment: Sorry, still does not work. still renders Europe.

Comment: Put `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` into viewDidLoad. If permission granted already, it might not get called in current location.

Comment: OMG it works!! Thank you so much for being patient and putting your time for it. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Please use this link and follow the steps to google map integration in iOS. [Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/current-place-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Use did change autorization delegate of location manager where you should use
start updating location then 
Remove private key before delegate methods and put below properties in did update location delegate methods. Remove stop update location method.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
       didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
   switch status {
   case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
      self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
      break

   case .denied, .restricted:
      self.disableLocationRelatedFeatures()
      break

   // Do nothing otherwise.
   default: break
   }
}

    self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
```